# How to stop the WKWebView while it is loading the request

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a `UIViewController` with  its `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight-64)];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.passageUrl]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
self.webView.UIDelegate = self;
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Now I want to do the popViewController action before the loading is finished, because the Internet connection is not good sometimes, I use the below code in its pop action, the code is executed at once but the webView cannot stop loading immediately, it will be a few seconds before the controller is popped out, anyone has some idea on how to solve this?

```
- (void)doBack:(id)sender {
    [self.webView stopLoading];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I found that in simulator it works well , so it turns out that the problem only exists in the device.

Comment: try to put in main thread ..

Comment: But I didn't start a new thread .

Comment: ok not an issue just check wheater it in the array of navigation or not ?

Comment: Yes, I have a subclass of `UITabbarController` as the rootViewController and its `viewControllers` is an array of navigation controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (id)popToViewControllerWithClassname:(NSString *)className Animated:(BOOL)animated {
    Class class =  NSClassFromString(className);
    for (UIViewController *controller in self.viewControllers) {
        if([controller isKindOfClass:class]) {
            [self popToViewController:controller animated:animated];
            return controller;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Call method

```
[self.navigationController popToViewControllerWithClassname:@"TestViewController" Animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks,I did as what you said, but it didn't work. Maybe the problem is not about the pop out action,maybe it is about the webView loading thing. I asked this question because my WKWebView always load slowly and cannot be stopped if it has started loading ,it bothered me a lot.So maybe I should try to improve my webView's reaction speed.